# Porting targeted information from one sheet to another

Tags: excel

let me first start with... I normally do not use excel, so total newbie here.

Sheet 1 is layed out like this...

(date ordered) , (qty) , (description) , (vendor), (reason)

On sheet 2, I want to be able to have it pull from the vendor column a specific vendor and port all of the columns regarding it to sheet 2.

So I can quickly look at sheet2, sheet3 etc... and see what has been ordered and spent with a specific vendor and to help me keep track as to what is being ordered from each vendor.

Thank you in advance for any and all replies.

Comment: Is there only one row per vendor?

Comment: 1 column, listing the various vendors. Going to copy and paste the line below.

Comment: 12/19/2013 1 11-11990 / AIRCRAFT WINGTIP NAVLIGHT CLEAR LENS COVER AIRCRAFT SPRUCE STOCK

Comment: Date, description, (aircraft spruce, vendor), stock

Comment: Can you describe sheet 2 a bit? How does it designate which vendor we're looking for?

Comment: I would like each sheet to be it's own designated sheet for each vendor. I want it to have the same layout at sheet 1, however to import all information say from vendor (Aircraft Spruce) and sheet 3 pull all information for vendor (Grainger) etc... I would like this to automatically pull the information I enter into sheet 1, to all the appropriate sheets.

Comment: Do you really need a separate sheet for each vendor?  A pivot table could do what you are looking for - http://i.imgur.com/etcandE.png - and all you need to see the next page of info is to change the vendor dropdown

Comment: I was asked to create a separate sheet for each vendor. I enter all information from all vendors onto sheet 1. Then they asked for me to create the separate sheets to view info per vendor.

Comment: How easy is it to make this pivot tab you spoke of?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro solution:

```
    Sub create_sheets_with_data()
        'assumes that "main" sheet contains data with a header row
        'needs to be run from "main" sheet

        'delete all sheets whose name contains "viewport"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "viewport", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'get last row
        last_row = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        'sort by vendor
        Rows("1:1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("main").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("main").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D" & last_row) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("main").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:E" & last_row)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        'for each vendor in "main" sheet, create a viewport to the data
        Dim r As Long, dest_row As Long
        r = 2
        last_vendor = ""
        cur_vendor = Range("d" & r).Value
        viewport_num = 0
        Do While Not cur_vendor = ""
            If cur_vendor = last_vendor Then
                'add current line to current viewport tab
                copy_line r, dest_row
                dest_row = dest_row + 1
            Else
                'create new viewport, copy over header, and copy current line
                If viewport_num > 0 Then Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                viewport_num = viewport_num + 1
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "viewport " & viewport_num
                copy_line 1, 1 'header
                copy_line r, 2 'current line
                dest_row = 3
            End If
            r = r + 1
            last_vendor = cur_vendor
            cur_vendor = Sheets("main").Range("d" & r).Value
        Loop
        If viewport_num > 0 Then Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Sheets("main").Activate
    End Sub

    Sub copy_line(src_r As Long, dest_r As Long)
        'copies line from "main" sheet to active sheet
        Sheets("main").Rows(src_r & ":" & src_r).Copy
        Range("a" & dest_r).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
```

I went with a macro solution as opposed to formulas because it seems to me that you could have new vendors added to the data at some point in the future. To avoid having to make sheets manually, I avoided formulas.

Please keep in mind that this solution will leave your main sheet sorted by vendor.

I hope that helps~

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try this and let you know how it works out for me.

Comment: I am not having any luck with all this. I am just not familiar enough with excel. And other people above me are not as well.

Comment: I have a photo of some of the information but it seems I can not upload it here to be viewed. Let me ask this... lines with, "  'text here " <--- are those comments and not part of the code? Where do I put this macro? I've tried looking it up and tried my best to learn it but I've just had no luck.

Comment: Is your Excel file an xlsx or an xlsm? You will need to convert it to an xlsm before you can use the code I provided. I can help with this. Let me know.

Comment: Comments start with a single quote. In my opinion, they are still part of the code, because they help with readability.